# Show div after delay on Magento 2 with JQuery

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I need to show this div after 3 seconds on my page.

```
    <div id="cratepop">
    <br>
    <center><img src="/shoppingcart.png"></center>
    <br>
    </div>
```

Tried using this but it's not working. Any help?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function($ ){


  $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#cratepop').show();
        }, 3000);     


        });


    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="cratepop" style="display:none;">
    <br>
        <center><img src="/shoppingcart.png"></center>
    <br>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('#cratepop').show();
        }, 5000);     
});
```

The only one thing you have to do is **HIDE** your DIV using CSS.

**jSfiddle** - https://jsfiddle.net/wqq8Lcka/13/

> **Note:** I dont recommend you to use inline CSS. this is just for an example.

Comment: Do I have to include the REQUIRE portion?

Comment: No.. 1st try removing it..

Comment: jQuery is not defined error

Comment: Current code  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            jQuery('#cratepop').show();
        }, 5000);     
});
</script>

Comment: thats because jQuery is not added in your site. Now try with REQUIRED portion.. Which was your original

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: Nope. Used this. <script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function($ ){


  $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $('#cratepop').show();
        }, 3000);     


        });


    });
</script>

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs/

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments yet so.. 
You are using this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('#cratepop').show();
    }, 5000);     
});
```

But in require you alias jquery as $ so simply replace jQuery with $ in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Add style="display:none;" in your code and everything will work fine.

```
   <div id="cratepop" style="display:none;">
    <br>
    <center><img src="/shoppingcart.png"></center>
    <br>
    </div>
```

Also try to show alert after 3 seconds..for testing purpose only :)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'],function($ ){

  $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
        alert('Joe is good');//for testing purpose only
        $('#cratepop').show();
        }, 3000);     
        });
    });
</script>
```